# Why fputc() when putc()?

Tags: c

`getc()` vs  `fgetc()`

`putc()` vs `fputc()`

What is the main difference between them?

I heard that both the functions do pretty much the same thing except getc() can be used as macros. What is meant by that?

If they are the same why use two functions are there to do the same things?

Any help would be seriously appreciated?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, printf vs fprintf is different: fprintf supports a file argument, printf goes to stdout.

The reason for fputc and fgetc is that putc and getc were, on historical implementations, macro versions that evaluated the argument more than once. For example, [the version on Unix V7](http://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V7/usr/include/stdio.h):

```
#define getc(p)   (--(p)->_cnt>=0? *(p)->_ptr++&0377:_filbuf(p))
#define putc(x,p) (--(p)->_cnt>=0? ((int)(*(p)->_ptr++=(unsigned)(x))):_flsbuf((unsigned)(x),p))
```

Every "p" in there is replaced with the expression you put in the argument - so if it has a side effect (like you called a function to get the file, or are iterating over a list of files with the ++ operator), it will be called multiple times and possibly operate on different files.

Some modern systems (FreeBSD or OSX, for example) still do this, but generally only in an "unlocked" version since the standard getc/putc functions must be thread-safe. The unlocked versions are used for performance inside the library functions, so the lock is acquired only once at the top of the library function (so that when you call printf, it doesn't have to call fputc hundreds of times, doing the lock every time).

Answer (score 0):

According to Kernighan's book putc is equivalent to fputc but putc could be implemented as a macro and putc may evaluate its stream argument more than once.

The difference between putc and fputc is that by using putc, you risk running the macro version which is inherently unsafe because it may have to evaluate its stream argument more than once. This causes complications that most people aren't aware of and thus do not watch out for, so fputc is better to use. fputc's macro does not have this problem.

Comment: Aren't the non f- functions simply macros with one of the arguments pre-supplied with `stdin`?

Comment: @BitFiddlingCodeMonkey No, I will add an example of one in an answer

Answer (score 0):

At least for `fprintf()` it's obvious, as one could specify the `FILE*` where to write to. `printf()`  print to `stdout`.

The other 2X2 functions indeed are equvivalent in terms of usage.